# Cocoa/ObjC: get CFBundleIdentifier of current process

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cfbundleidentifier

I have a case where `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]` does only contain this:

```
17.09.11 18:28:26,936 [0x0-0x5a98a93].com.valvesoftware.steam: 2011-09-17 18:28:26.935 steam[85587:707] infodict: {
17.09.11 18:28:26,936 [0x0-0x5a98a93].com.valvesoftware.steam:     CFBundleExecutablePath = "/Applications/Spiele/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/osx32/steam";
17.09.11 18:28:26,936 [0x0-0x5a98a93].com.valvesoftware.steam:     NSBundleInitialPath = "/Applications/Spiele/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/osx32";
17.09.11 18:28:26,936 [0x0-0x5a98a93].com.valvesoftware.steam:     NSBundleResolvedPath = "/Applications/Spiele/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/osx32";
17.09.11 18:28:26,936 [0x0-0x5a98a93].com.valvesoftware.steam: }
```

But I want to get the CFBundleIdentifier.

Is there another (more general) way to get the CFBundleIdentifier of the current process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:getpid()] bundleIdentifier]` works.

Comment: You're always far better than me :)

Comment: Does `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]` work? That would be the easiest solution...

Comment: @MrMage: No, that returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *CFBundleIdentifier = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];


(CFBundleIdentifier = @"com.yourcompany.yourapp")
```